# How to close the output panel in a vscode plugin after run vscode.tasks.executeTask()?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins

In my vscode plugin, some command run a process using executeTask():

```
function run_process(process, args) {
  vscode.tasks.executeTask(
    new vscode.Task(
      { type: "MyTask" },
      vscode.TaskScope.Workspace,
      "wgtool",
      "no source",
      new vscode.ShellExecution(process, args)
    )
  );
}
```

After the process exit, I have to close a panel with "output | debug | console | ..." manually. Can I close the panel in run_process()?

in package.json:

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "taskDefinitions": [
      {
        "type": "MyTask"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I read the source code/document, "interface TaskPresentationOptions" or "tasks.json" is close to my question, but I don't know how to use them with my run_process().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To automatically close the output panel after running a task in a VS Code extension, you can use the `vscode.window.createOutputChannel` method to create an output channel and then dispose of it when the task completes.

Here's an example of how you can modify your run_process function to achieve this:

```js
const vscode = require('vscode');

function run_process(process, args) {
  // Create a unique output channel
  const outputChannel = vscode.window.createOutputChannel('MyOutputChannel');

  const task = new vscode.Task(
    { type: 'MyTask' },
    vscode.TaskScope.Workspace,
    'wgtool',
    'no source',
    new vscode.ShellExecution(process, args)
  );

  // Attach the output channel to the task
  task.presentationOptions = {
    reveal: vscode.TaskRevealKind.Silent,
    clear: true,
  };
  task.outputChannel = outputChannel;

  // Execute the task
  vscode.tasks.executeTask(task).then((execution) => {
    // Listen for the end of the task
    const listener = vscode.tasks.onDidEndTaskProcess((e) => {
      if (e.execution === execution) {
        // Dispose of the output channel when the task ends
        outputChannel.dispose();
        listener.dispose();
      }
    });
  });
}

// Usage
run_process('your_process_command', ['arg1', 'arg2']);
```

Comment: task.presentationOptions = {} is what i am looking for. 
I use task.presentationOptions = {close: true}, then the output panel closed automatically. thank you!